# Permission issues when trying to restore files from an image

Tags: windows-7, macrium

Even though I've checked the box stating that I want to 'Enable Access to Restricted Folders', I keep getting permission errors.

I'm running version 5, build 5154.

The folders that I'm having an issue with are folders from a Windows Vista image, \Users\aaa. I get prompted to make changes in the Security Tab. If I try to change the owner, I get an error about the media being write protected.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the Macrium image into a VHD, mounted the volume and was able to access all my files without any issues.